# Maximal ideal in $R[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

So the ideal $(x)\subset R[x]$ in an integral domain $R$ (which is not a field) is not a maximal ideal because $R[x] / (x)$ is not a field.

If it is not a maximal ideal, there must be at least one ideal in $R[x]$ which contains $(x)$.

Am I right that $(x, 2)$ (the ideal spanned by $x$ and $2$) is such an ideal? Are there other examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$; then
$$
I'=\{p(x)\in R[x]:p(0)\in I\}
$$
is an ideal in $R[x]$, $I'\supseteq(x)$ and
$$
R[x]/I'\cong R/I
$$
Hence $I'$ is maximal if and only if $I$ is maximal.

Your specific example (which works for $R=\mathbb{Z}$, but not necessarily in other rings) is for $I=2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But doesn't that contradict the fact (Nullstellensatz) that the maximal ideals in $R[x]$ are precisely those that are generated by $n$ monoms, i.e. the ideals $(x_1-a_1,\cdots,x_n-a_n)$? If $R=\mathbb Z$, then why does the above example not work? Why can the ideal $(x_1-a_1,\cdots,x_n-a_n)$ not be "enlarged" to $(x_1-a_1,\cdots,x_n-a_n, 2)$?

Comment: @Bass Shouldn't $R$ be a field for Nullstellensatz?

Comment: Oh of course. And in a field, the addition of $2$ would blow up the ideal to the whole ring. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any maximal ideals in $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ for a general ring $R$?

Comment: @Bass Yes, of course: take a maximal ideal $I$ of $R$ and do the same as in my answer.

Comment: I see. For $\mathbb Z$, take $I=2\mathbb Z$, then $I$ is the ideal of polynomials with remainder $c_0=2$, which is maximal because $I$ is. Right?